# Selecting String after particular character in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to select string after a particular character

here is my string :

> CNTYRIST-COVENTRY-15-290

in this string i want to select string between last 2 "-" i.e 15

how to do this in javascript?

Comment: Simple without regex `"CNTYRIST-COVENTRY-15-290".split("-")[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript ,

```
var text = "CNTYRIST-COVENTRY-15-290";

var arraytext = text.split('-');

var result = arraytext[2];

//now this is stored in result
```

See the fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/wVtLw/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
"CNTYRIST-COVENTRY-15-290".split('-')[2];
```

`.split('-')` splits the string by `-` and returns the array, where 15 is the third element, and whose index is 2, by which I'm accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could easilt split the string into an array and the grab the third part.

Like this:

`var fifteen = "CNTYRIST-COVENTRY-15-290".split("-")[2]`

Here's a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/VBXB4/).

The idea is that split takes and string, parses it by a character(s), then creates and array. You then reach into that array, and grab the index of 2, which in this case is "15".

More on split here -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using JavaScript's `.split` method on strings:

```
var str = "CNTYRIST-COVENTRY-15-290";
var num = str.split('-')[1];
```

That splits up the string into an array of three, splitting it up at the `-` in the string. Then you select the second element in the array (index `1`), which will be the string `"15"`.

Answer (score 0):

`var str = "CNTYRIST-COVENTRY-15-290";
 var pos = str.lastIndexOf("-");
 var sub = str.substring(0, pos); 
 var pos1 = sub.lastIndexOf("-");
 var sub1 = str.substring(pos, pos1+1);
 alert(sub1); // 15`